# Is it possible to create a link between 2 iOS apps?

Tags: ios

I'm a semi-technical UX designer looking for a technical solution on a topic where none of our developers are fully informed, so bear with me.

Our organization has multiple iOS apps, each of which does somewhat different things. I'd like to create a link between two of these apps such that an interaction in one app will open the other app and take it to a specific state.

If these were web applications, we could easily do this via a simple link. Is such a thing possible in the iOS world? And if so, without getting deep into the weeds on the technical details, can you point me in the general direction of the technical approach we would want to take so I can have our developers start researching further?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to forward your developers onto Apple's documentation on ["Inter-app communication"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2):

And most likely you'll want to use an app url scheme:

> A URL scheme lets you communicate with other apps through a protocol that you define. To communicate with an app that implements such a scheme, you must create an appropriately formatted URL and ask the system to open it. To implement support for a custom scheme, you must declare support for the scheme and handle incoming URLs that use the scheme.

Comment: Perfect! I was hoping some scheme like that existed where we could create URL links for apps to manage. Thank you!